# Spring Security OAuth2 grants a token, then immediately can't remember it: Access is denied (user is anonymous)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I get a token

```
$ curl -u badge:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=admin -d password=admin -d client_id=badge -d client_secret=123456 -d scope=write
{"access_token":"00a872f9-6f6e-4073-af17-d07d3991c2f0","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"8772d67c-682a-4b56-ae51-5a4bc4dceff7","expires_in":43199,"scope":"write"}
```

Then immediately try to use it

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 00a872f9-6f6e-4073-af17-d07d3991c2f0" -d '{"apiKey": "key", "tag": "tag"}' localhost:8080/isTagAvailable
```

But it says I'm anonymous!

```
2018-05-26 23:43:28.390 DEBUG 54284 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /isTagAvailable at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-05-26 23:43:28.391 DEBUG 54284 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
```

Why?

`OAuth2Configurtion.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient(applicationName)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
            .authorities("ROLE_USER")
//          .scopes("read", "write")
            .scopes("write")
            .resourceIds(applicationName)
            .secret("123456");
    }
```

`SecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity//(debug=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/isTagAvailable").authenticated()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/robots.txt", "/error", "/login", "/doLogout", "/home", "/pageNotFound"
                    ).permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable();
    }
```

`Version`

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
```

---

I added

```
    .anonymous().disable()
```

But now it gives

```
2018-05-27 00:42:54.987 DEBUG 54284 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/isTagAvailable'; against '/isTagAvailable'
2018-05-27 00:42:54.987 DEBUG 54284 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /isTagAvailable; Attributes: [authenticated]
2018-05-27 00:42:54.988 DEBUG 54284 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

It still can't remember the token!

Answer (score 0):

I threw away `@EnableWebSecurity` and `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which just totally breaks the app. I thought they were required to get access to `HttpSecurity` which I thought I needed. I discovered this simple new class will solve the problem.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    String [] ignoredPaths = new String[]{...};

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(ignoredPaths).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .httpBasic();   
    }
```